# For loop skipping error

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, gtrendsr

I would like get google trend data through a for loop. However, an error is holding me back. After searching through other stack questions I still cannot make it work. The loop in question:

```
a2p = for (i in dfurlnames$names1)
{ 
    x<- paste(i)
    gtrends_function3(x)
}
```

In my for loop I get the following error:

```
Error : res$status_code == 200 is not TRUE
```

I use the following packages and function:

Get the new gtrendsR; devtools::install_github('PMassicotte/gtrendsR')

```
library(gtrendsR)

gtrends_function3 <- function(x)
{
    trend1 = gtrends(c(x), geo = c(""), time = "2014-01-05 2014-10-04")
    trend_df1 = ldply(trend1)
    return(as.numeric(trend_df1$hits))        
}
```

The list:

```
dfurlnames$names1 = Ang babaeng humayo, The Bad Batch, Une vie, La La Land,               
The Light Between Oceans, El ciudadano ilustre, Spira Mirabilis, La región 
salvaje, Nocturnal Animals
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to really know for certain. You can step through your code by manually setting `i <- dfurlnames$names1[1]` (iterating over each within `dfurlnames`), running `gtrends(i, ...)` (use your opts) and see which is causing the problem. BTW: your use of `paste` and `c` here is unnecessary, doing nothing.

Comment: The error indicates that the HTTP request failed for some reason. Could be there is some issue with your names.

Comment: When there is an error in an R `for`-loop, the value of the iterator counter remains in the global environment, so you should simply type `i` at a console prompt which should tell you which of the `dfurlnames$names1` is causing the problem. (That "list" does not look like any sort of output that one would expect from R.)

Comment: @neilfws That is correct. There is a problem with "La región 
salvaje". But how can I get the loop to return an NA or just skip the google trends call for that name and get the rest of the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status code 200 refers to the HTTP protocol, indicating that everything went ok.  Probably, you are requesting things too fast in the for loop.  Add a sleep command, e.g.:

> Sys.sleep(1)

in your for loop to slow things down.  Alternatively, use a tryCatch to bypass:

```
a2p = for (i in dfurlnames$names1)
{ 
    tryCatch({
       x<- paste(i)
       gtrends_function3(x)
    }, error=function(e) {print(e)})
}
```

Comment: The error code indicates that for a certain value the response code IS NOT 200. The problem here is that I would like to skip that value and continue with the loop.

Comment: Also, a for loop always returns null, so there's no point in assigning it to a variable.